# SCORM API Conformance Docs?

Tags: documentation, scorm, standards-compliance, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I'm looking for SCORM Conformance docs for all the various versions. The SCORM 2004 3rd & 4th Edition docs are relatively easy to find, but I can't find anything for the other versions.

Wanting to find the docs so I can write my own tests for a Chrome Extension (which also provides a dummy storage backed API for testing content away from an LMS) - and have it able to also test and report in a useful way.

If there aren't any specific docs for this, then pointing me at the source code for any tests that are required for conformance would be useful.

Most importantly I'm after SCORM 1.1/1.2 data, due to the run-time reference not differentiating between those two, and the error strings on that page being somewhat lacking.

- SCORM 1.1
- SCORM 1.2
- SCORM 2004 2nd Edition
- [SCORM 2004 3rd Edition](http://www.adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/SCORM.2004.3ED.ConfReq.v1.0.pdf)
- [SCORM 2004 4th Edition](http://www.adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/SCORM_2004_4ED_v1_1_TR_20090814.pdf)

*TinCan / xAPI isn't needed (not sure if I want to be intercepting AJAX calls for a dummy API) - but if someone has links they'd be useful if I do add it.*

Comment: Tin Can is a whole 'nother animal, I would focus on SCORM first then decide whether to tackle xAPI. If you decide to try xAPI, there are open-source projects you could use as starting points.

Comment: That's my thought - but I'm putting together a complete SCORM tester extension, so I might eventually if I get a client at work that wants it (this is a home project) :-)

Comment: Even on the SCORM side thats a pretty lengthy quest.  There are platforms running parallel API's (Both API and API_1484_11 are exposed at the same time).  Situations where the API is making round trips to the server on gets and sets - resulting in 250+ms of lag per call.  SCORM 1.2/1.1 for the most part was all optional so you should be able to bust through that fast.  But SCORM 2004 with all the nested dependancies on the imsmanifest.xml makes for a rough series of use cases.  Lots of curve balls just in the interpretation of the standards and what passes for "compliance".

Comment: This is a browser extension, so only provides an API, and doesn't actually have anything to do with the content pack or manifest - although for another project at work I've had to do all the content pack / manifest side of things so could technically make a client-side SCORM LMS - that would only really be limited by browser memory footprint and CPU usage ;-)

Answer (score 4):

For 1.2: http://adlnet.gov/adl-research/scorm/scorm-1-2 contains official links to the SCORM 1.2 "[Technical Specification](http://adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/SCORM_1_2_pdf.zip)" (in a ZIP) and the old [SCORM 1.2 Conformance Test Suite](http://adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/SCORM1_2_TestSuite1_2_7ST.zip).

[All SCORM 1.x specs](http://www.scorm12.com/) (and conformance suites) courtesy JCA Solutions

[All SCORM 2004 specs](http://www.scorm2004.net/) courtesy JCA Solutions

[SCORM 2004 2nd Edition specs](http://scorm.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/scorm-2004-2nd-edition-documentation.zip) courtesy Rustici Software

The late [Claude Ostyn's site](http://www.ostyn.com/resources.htm) is still useful for older SCORM resources and examples.

SCORM 1.1 was really short-lived; considering how quickly SCORM 1.2 replaced it, and considering 1.1 was released almost exactly 15 years ago, I doubt there is anyone actively using it. Probably not worth your time. See http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/business-of-scorm/scorm-versions/

Comment: I'm only wanting to add all the versions for completeness - and because I want to be able to run quick and simple conformance tests on any server running that version - those links should give me enough to get things started with for the older versions :-)

Comment: The best starting point for xAPI conformance is probably http://tincanapi.com/conformance-test/